# App_Code "Add Class" Greyed Out

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm new to developing web applications, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this properly. What I'm trying to do is create a C# class with some common functions that my ASPX.CS classes can inherit from, to eliminate redundant code.

I've added an App_Code folder to my project's root directory. When I right-click on that folder in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, then select *Add*, the *Class* option is greyed out.

Likewise, if I create a class from *File > New > File*, then manually put it into the App_Code folder, it's inaccessible. It'll be visible if I select *Show All Files* in the Solution Explorer, but right-clicking on it has *Include in Project* greyed-out too.

[image]

How do I create a class that my other ASPX.CS classes can inherit from?

Comment: Are you currently debugging or otherwise running ?

Comment: You can't add new class while debugging. Try to use hot key `Shift-F5` to stop debugging.

Comment: I forgot I still had the project running. I can't believe it was that simple, haha. Thank you!